# Django best practice for common class

Tags: python, django

I would like to make class like common.py and access from each application's `views.py` or `management/commands`

For now my structure is like this

```
myproj/myproj
      /myapplication/views.py 
                    /management/commands/mycommand.py
```

then I add my orivinal class and call from each files like this.

However , where should I put common.py and how to import???

For example making newfolder ??
 but it might be confusing for application name??

```
myproj/myproj
      /myapplication/views.py 
                    /management/commands/mycommand.py
      /commonlib/common.py
```

How is the best practice for this purpose??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's generic to lots of different apps, I often create something at the top level, so it's like:

```
myproj/myproj/helpers
```

inside helpers, put:

```
utilities.py
```

and then in your view or command, use:

```
from myproj.helpers import utilities
```

You could put any number of generic files into your helpers folder, and import them anywhere from that location.

Often it depends what feels most organised for you :)